# Multitouput regression with AutoSklearn (AutoML) Error

Tags: automl, auto-sklearn

I'm trying to use AutoSklearn to perform multiouput regression over a dataset but I'm receiving the error "Regression with data of type multiclass-multioutput is not supported. Supported types are ['continuous', 'binary', 'multiclass', 'continuous-multioutput']".

I'm using AutoSklearn for multioutput regression (due to project constraints I had to use this tool instead of another more suitable approach); however, during the fit of the model, the following error is raised "Regression with data of type multiclass-multioutput is not supported. Supported types are ['continuous', 'binary', 'multiclass', 'continuous-multioutput']".

Here is a small sample of my data: [Dataset Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCQQR.png)

I'm using as X train, a numpy.array with the features year, month, day, weekday and holiday with a shape (3, 5). As y train, I also have a numpy.array with the features seg_1, seg_2, and seg_3 with a shape (3, 3).

I tried to replicate the example in https://automl.github.io/auto-sklearn/master/examples/20_basic/example_multioutput_regression.html and it works, but mine doesn't.

Appreciate the help.